# Excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This month = 5
Last month = 1

In theory, `= (5-1)/5` would be a 400% increase, yet Excel returns .80 or 80%.

How would my formula show the 400% increase rather than 80%?

Comment: If you're comparing to last month, use last month in the denominator.

Comment: (5-1)/5 = 4/5 which is < 1 says Math.

Comment: This is an algebra problem. Last month is A. Next month is B. X is the increase you are looking for. The equation is A + (A*X) = B  Use algebra to subtract A from both sides and then divide by A and you will end up  X=(B-A)/A or X=(5-1)/1 or X=400%

Comment: thank you Vaughn and fixer1234 but in same spreadsheet i have the following:  This month : 400  last month : 1200.......same logic above would be =(400-1200)/400 = -66%  but that should be -200%........i get the one side = 400% but same logic within same spreadsheet doesnt return same....please let me know what i am missing

Answer (score 2):

In English:

```
=(ThisMonth-LastMonth)/Lastmonth
```

In Excel:

```
=(5.0-1.0)/1.0
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Gary student - see my comment above... thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

In reply to your additional comment. -66% is the answer you are looking for, -200% of 1200 would be -1200.

This month you sold 400 units whereas last month you sold 1200 units, that is 66% less units sold than last month. Not 200% less